# History and modified HTML by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I've run into a small problem with browsers history when the page is modified by JavaScript.

**how to reproduce**

1. Opened page with the elements which can be deleted. Then I hit delete button which triggers JavaScript with ajax and `jquery.remove()`
2. Then I hit some link to open another page
3. On new page I will hit the browsers back button
4. I'm on the page with deleted element which actually doesn't exist in the database.

What is the solution? Clear browser history? (can I?)

### SOLUTION

Thanks to Endy and the source I've come with some solution:

- Create in HTML template an input[type=hidden] with name deleted (whatever)
- Create elements which can be deleted with unique ID
- When is the delete action is triggered, add the unique ID to delete input

  ***var deleted     = $("input[name=deleted]"); deleted.val(deleted.val()+id+";");***
- On document ready create checker which removes the elements

**How it works**
The browsers automatically remembers the values which are added to the input so when the page is showed from cache it has the value and document ready is triggered

*Code:*

```js
var deleted     = $("input[name=deleted]");
if (deleted.length > 0 && deleted.val() != "") {
    var deletedInput    = deleted.val();
    var deletedArray    = deletedInput.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < deletedArray.length;i++) {
        if (deletedArray[i] != "") {
            $("#photo"+deletedArray[i]).remove();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not easily doable. Check http://forum.jquery.com/topic/howto-force-page-reload-refresh-of-previous-page-when-back-button-is-pressed and http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137518

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the browser history. What you could do is always forcing a Javascript forward on the page where you deleted stuff.

```
window.history.forward();
```

Or, better, when going back modify the page so it is in sync with your database.

Comment: No great idea, because when user go to your page 1, changes some elements in page, then go forward to page 2 and back to page 1, changes elements on page and the action triggers window.history.forward(); and then the user is forwarded to page 2